# read big file in php (more than 500mb)

Tags: php, readfile

I need to read a large file to find some labels and create a dynamic form. I can not use `file()` or `file_get_contents()` because the file size.
If I read the file line by line with the following code

```
set_time_limit(0);    
$handle = fopen($file, 'r');
    set_time_limit(0);
    if ($handle) {
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            $line = fgets($handle);
            if ($line) {            
             //do something.
            }
        }
    }

    echo 'Read complete';
```

I get the following error in Chrome:

> Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)

This error occurs after several minutes so that the constant `max_input_time`, I think not is the problem.(is set to 60).

Comment: How much RAM do you have available?

Comment: I have looked the use of the ram memory in task manager. This fully. why? if I'm reading the file line by line ...

Answer (score 1):

What browser software do you use? Apache, nginx? You should set the max accepted file upload at somewhere higher than 500MB. Furthermore, the max upload size in the php.ini should be bigger than 500MB, too, and I think that PHP must be allowed to spawn processes larger than 500MB. (check this in your php config).

Comment: I use apache...but i dont understand. I do not want to upload the file (The file is already on the server) , I just want to read line by line to find some matches ...

Comment: Oh sorry, than I misunderstood you. What operating system are you using? What is the RAM size of your server, and the max allowed RAM usage of one single apache process?

Comment: I'm used windows 7 and xampp. 4gb Ram...Where I can see this?  max allowed RAM usage of one single apache process?

Answer (score 1):

Set the memory limit `ini_set("memory_limit","600M");`also you need to set the time out limit

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally long running processes should not be done while the users waits for them to complete.
I'd recommend using a background job oriented tool that can handle this type of work and can be queried about the status of the job (running/finished/error).

My first guess is that something in the middle breaks the connection because of a timeout. Whether it's a timeout in the web server (which PHP cannot know about) or some firewall, it doesn't really matter, PHP gets a signal to close the connection and the script stops running. You could circumvent this behaviour by using [ignore-user-abort(true)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php), this along with set_time_limit(0) should do the trick.

The caveat is that whatever caused the connection abort will still do it, though the script would still finish it's job. One very annoying side effect is that this script could possibly be executed multiple times in parallel without neither of them ever completing.

Again, I recommend using some background task to do it and an interface for the end-user (browser) to verify the status of that task. You could also implement a basic one yourself via cron jobs and database/text files that hold the status.

Comment: Thanks for responding. the problem is that the RAM reaches full but I do not understand why reading a file line by line makes much use of the ram. Use a background process would cause the same problem?

Comment: I think this solution is good(I recommend using some background task to do it and an interface for the end-user (browser) to verify the status of that task. You could also implement a basic one yourself via cron jobs and database/text files that hold the status.) But ¿How I can cancel the process? if the user have a form with the process status and a button to cancel it?

Comment: That would require an interface for the background process and the web server to communicate. If you only need to signal a "kill" for the process you can do it via APC (or alike). It's capable of sharing objects between PHP processes, so you can have a shared key that the job checks periodically.
About the RAM issue, if you're not using some old version of PHP then some variables are probably not being cleared. Try "unset"ing every possible variable and clearing all of the objects (notice any dispose/clear/close methods).